Burning Annotations in a PDF with an OverlayView
I achieved using PDFkit alongside Pencilkit with overlay views using a PKDrawing on top of a PDFView following the guidance of the apple developer guide (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10089/), it works with scrolling and zooming in and out, but now I want to burn in the annotations in the pdf so they become one and everytime the user backs out of the view or closes the app, the annotations stay with the PDF. I want to save the updated PDF after merging the annotations and the next time the pdf is selected in the view it appears with the annotations already merged.
Working local PDF with PDFView with PencilkitOverlay
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import PencilKit
import UIKit

struct PdfDocumentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("PDF Viewer")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
        
            MyPDFPage(pdfFileName: "W3dummyPDFfile")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct MyPDFPage: View {
    let pdfFileName: String
    let pdfURL: URL?
    
    init(pdfFileName: String) {
        self.pdfFileName = pdfFileName
        self.pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfFileName, withExtension: "pdf")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PDFViewWrapper(pdfURL: pdfURL)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct PDFViewWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var pdfURL: URL?
    var coordinator = OverlayCoordinator()enter image description here
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.pageOverlayViewProvider = coordinator
        pdfView.delegate = coordinator
        pdfView.isInMarkupMode = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        
        if let url = pdfURL, let document = PDFDocument(url: url) {
            pdfView.document = document
        }
        
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.addSubview(pdfView)
        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.leadingAnchor),
            pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.trailingAnchor),
            pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor),
            pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.topAnchor)
        ])
        
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    }
}


class OverlayCoordinator: NSObject, PDFPageOverlayViewProvider, PDFViewDelegate {
  var pageToViewMapping = [PDFPage: PKCanvasView]()
  var toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
   
  func pdfView(_ view: PDFView, overlayViewFor page: PDFPage) -> UIView? {
    var resultView: PKCanvasView? = nil
     
    if let overlayView = pageToViewMapping[page] {
      resultView = overlayView
    } else {
      let canvasView = PKCanvasView(frame: .zero)
      canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
      canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
      canvasView.isOpaque = false
      pageToViewMapping[page] = canvasView
        
      //PKToolPicker
      toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
      toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
      canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
      resultView = canvasView
    }
      
    return resultView
  }
}


#Preview {
    MyPDFPage(pdfFileName: "W3dummyPDFfile")
}

I previously achieved saving the annotations but It was using an externalURL where I fetched the pdf from my AWS3 bucket, but figured it was a pain to download the pdf, looking for a path for the file then the next time it opens it automatically opens the saved pdf then implement the burn annotations so, anyone knows If there is a way to also do that to decrease the space in the local iPad, or if fetching the url with the URLSession is the way to go ?

Working PDFURL with PDFView with PencilkitOverlay
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import PencilKit
import UIKit

struct PDFDocumentView: View {
  let externalPDFURL = URL(string: "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf")!
   
  @State private var loadAnnotations = false
  @State private var saveAnnotations = false
   
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: {
        loadAnnotations.toggle()
      }) {
        Text("Load Annotations")
      }
      Button(action: {
        saveAnnotations.toggle()
      }) {
        Text("Save Annotations")
      }
       
      if let pdfDocument = loadPDF(from: externalPDFURL) {
        PDFViewWrapper(pdfDocument: pdfDocument, loadAnnotations: $loadAnnotations, saveAnnotations: $saveAnnotations)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      } else {
        Text("Error loading PDF from URL")
      }
    }
  }
   
  func loadPDF(from url: URL) -> PDFDocument? {
    do {
      let pdfData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
      return PDFDocument(data: pdfData)
    } catch {
      print("Error loading PDF from URL: \(error)")
      return nil
    }
  }
}

struct PDFViewWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  var pdfDocument: PDFDocument
  @Binding var loadAnnotations: Bool
  @Binding var saveAnnotations: Bool
  var coordinator: OverlayCoordinator = OverlayCoordinator()
   
  
  @State private var saveTimer: Timer?
   
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    pdfView.pageOverlayViewProvider = coordinator
    pdfView.document = pdfDocument
    pdfView.delegate = coordinator
    pdfView.isInMarkupMode = true
    pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
    pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
     
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    viewController.view.addSubview(pdfView)
    pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.leadingAnchor),
      pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.trailingAnchor),
      pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor),
      pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.topAnchor)
    ])
     
    startSaveTimer()
     
    return viewController
  }
   
  
  func startSaveTimer() {
    
    saveTimer?.invalidate()
     
    
    saveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15, repeats: true) { _ in
      coordinator.saveDrawings()
    }
  }
   
  
  func stopSaveTimer() {
    saveTimer?.invalidate()
    saveTimer = nil
  }
   
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    
    if loadAnnotations {
      coordinator.loadDrawings()
      
      loadAnnotations = false
    }
     
    
    if saveAnnotations {
      coordinator.saveDrawings()
      
      saveAnnotations = false
    }
  }
}

class OverlayCoordinator: NSObject, PDFPageOverlayViewProvider, PDFViewDelegate {
  var pageToViewMapping = [PDFPage: PKCanvasView]()
  var toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
   
  
  func saveDrawings() {
    for (page, canvasView) in pageToViewMapping {
      let drawingData = canvasView.drawing.dataRepresentation()
      let filePath = getDrawingFilePath(for: page)
       
      
      do {
        try drawingData.write(to: filePath)
        print("Drawing saved to: \(filePath)")
      } catch {
        print("Failed to save drawing: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }
   
  
  func loadDrawings() {
    for (page, canvasView) in pageToViewMapping {
      let filePath = getDrawingFilePath(for: page)
       
      
      if let drawingData = try? Data(contentsOf: filePath), let drawing = try? PKDrawing(data: drawingData) {
        canvasView.drawing = drawing
      }
    }
  }
   
  
  func getDrawingFilePath(for page: PDFPage) -> URL {
    
    let pageIndex = page.pageRef?.pageNumber ?? 0
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let filePath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    return filePath.appendingPathComponent("drawing_page_\(pageIndex).dat")
  }
   
  func pdfView(_ view: PDFView, overlayViewFor page: PDFPage) -> UIView? {
    var resultView: PKCanvasView? = nil
     
    if let canvasView = pageToViewMapping[page] {
      resultView = canvasView
    } else {
      let canvasView = PKCanvasView(frame: .zero)
      canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
      canvasView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly
      canvasView.isOpaque = false
      pageToViewMapping[page] = canvasView
       
      //PKToolPicker
      toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder:  canvasView)
      toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
      canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
       
      resultView = canvasView
    }
     
    return resultView
  }
}
#Preview {
 PDFDocumentView()
}


figure it out ?
